# Trigger event from ChannelFactory

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5

We are using the ChannelFactory to connect to our WCF Service. When ever I do a call to the service, I want the Channel factory to trigger another event. Something like 'OnFunctionCall'. How can I add such a event handler to the ChannelFactory. I'm kinda rushed for time, so I hope someone could help.

Working with C#, .net 3.5 SP1

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to create an endpoint behavior and attach it to the factory endpoint (see below). That behavior would add an inspector to the channels the factory creates (which can be either an `IClientMessageInspector` or an `IParameterInspector`), and your inspector would trigger the OnFunctionCall event whenever a message is sent to the server.

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(...);
factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyInspector());
```

For more information on message inspectors you can look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx, and for parameter inspectors you can look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/26/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector.aspx.